# What is the compatible pointer type when I pass it as a reference of a pointer to a function that goes through another function in C?

Tags: c, pointers, reference, linked-list, pass-by-reference

I know that in order for caller's memory to reflect the changes to the callee's local parameter, you need to pass the parameter as the reference to the pointer.  And when I use `Push(1, &h1);  Push(3, &h1);  Push(5, &h1);` directly, a correct list is created and printed.  But if I go through `createList(&h1);` to call `Push(..., &h1)`, the compiler gives
`warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'struct ListNode ***' to parameter of type 'struct ListNode **'; remove & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`, and no list is created.  After I did what the compiler said - removing the &, and I still get no list.

My question: What is the compatible pointer type when I pass it as a reference of a pointer to a function that goes through another function in C?

```
void Push(int val, struct ListNode **headRef){
  struct ListNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));

  newNode->val = val;
  newNode->next = *headRef;
  *headRef = newNode;
}

void createList(struct ListNode **head){
  int num;

  printf("Enter data to create a list. (Enter -1 to end)\n");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  while (num != -1){ 
    Push(num, &head); // Note: the '&'
    scanf("%d", &num);
  }
}

int main(){
  createList(&h1);
  printList(h1);
}

void printList(struct ListNode *head){
  struct ListNode *curr= head;

  while (curr != NULL) {
    printf("%d ", curr->val);    
    curr = curr->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: There are no "references" in C. Only pointers.

Comment: Look at your declaration of `createList`; it expects the address of a pointer to a `ListNode`. Now look at `Push`. It expects the same thing. So why would you call `Push` with `&head` when you already had exactly what `Push` needs? (ie, `head`).

Comment: @CareyGregory, no, given the function signatures presented (which look fine to me), if `createList(&h)` is type-correct, then so is `Push(1, &h)`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Nothing wrong with the function signatures, but `&head` is a `ListNode ***`, not a `ListNode **`. Hence the warning.

Comment: @CareyGregory, yes, you're right.  I needed to read the code a little more carefully.  What I meant was that if `createList(&h)` was correct, then so must be `Push(1, &h)` *when called from the same scope*.  I missed the call from inside `createList()`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart , I see people using the words, reference, pointer and address interchangeably. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @PumpkinCake: How about some research on your own? google and Wikipedia down?

Comment: @Olaf , I know C only has pass-by-value.  But I wasn't sure if that's what Jonathon Reinhart meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `Push` in `createList` you need to pass `head`, not `&head`.

`Push` expects a `ListNode **`.  The `head` variable in `createList` is also of type `ListNode **`, so no need to take its address or dereference it when calling `Push`.

When in `createList`, `head` contains the address of `h1`.  If you pass that same value to `Push`, then in that function `headRef` also contains the address of `h1`.

I ran your code with `Push(num, head);` and it appeared to output what you would expect.